# Update Query not working and Execution time taking too long

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to update the table1 with table2 column "sc"
here is my

**table1**

| CP |
| --- |
| stab |
| crawl |
| dred |
| sab |

**table2**

| CP | SC |
| --- | --- |
| stab | stab |
| crawl | crawl.com |
| dred | dredal |
| sab | sab |

So I was trying to update column table1 "CP", If table2 CP<>SC then to update table1 CP with SC else CP the common field in both table is cp,The execution time is going on infinite while trying below query

So here is the update query which I am trying so far:-

```
update table1
set table1=try.ss from

(select table1.cp,
    CASE
        WHEN table1.cp = table2.cp THEN sc
        ELSE table1.cp
    END ss
from
    tr.table1
    left join table2 on table1.cp = table2.cp
) as try
```

Comment: Any approach will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
update table1 set table1.cp = source.sc
from (select * from table2 where cp <> sc ) source
where table1.cp = source.cp;

select * from table1;

+-----------+
|    CP     |
+-----------+
| stab      |
| crawl.com |
| dredal    |
| sab       |
+-----------+
```

Comment: using this query it is taking a very long time since the data is more